# Unable to view provider hosted app (Server to Server)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, provider-hosted-app

I published an app on my dev server to be installed in sharepoint 2013, but I can not view the default.aspx page, invalid certificate prompts

[image]

Comment: Have you configured the SSL certificate? what you get when trying HTTP?

Comment: This site can’t be reached

Comment: Yup I also created a self-signed certificate

Comment: Refer this link : http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/An-Error-Occurred-While-Processing-your-request-SharePoint-Office-365-with-Provider-Hosted-Application

Answer (score 0):

This caused by site authentication usually when you configure your add-in web site per my experience, You may try the steps in my demo guideline [here](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AoQOaLRAiCQPgxxcBR3g8yfrJ7Bz).

[Thread for your reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fc21c3f2-66ee-4dcc-adbd-a4637cf368fc/is-it-possible-to-run-multiple-hightrust-provider-hosted-addin-appweb-through-a-single-port-443?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

Comment: Already followed your guide but unfortunately same error :(